# Can we call procedure inside function in oracle PL/SQL? If not then why?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In some places I heard that we cannot call procedure inside function in oracle PL/SQL. May I know why is it so?
Also why cant we call a procedure within a SELECT statement whereas we can call a function in the same SELECT statement.

Comment: *"In some places I heard that we cannot call procedure inside function in oracle PL/SQL."* Where did your hear this? It's wrong, completely wrong. So now you know not to trust that person/site/book as a source of Oracle expertise.

Comment: I don't think asking *"I heard ..."*  type questions is a good use of this site. Precisely because these assertions come without any citation or reference, or offer any justification. They just expect us to explain some random statement. I encourage you to push back the next somebody tells you such garbage. Ask them to explain why. Ask them whether they have tested it, what happened when they did, etc. Quite other you'll find they haven't tried it for themselves and they're just passing on something they read (or misunderstood) on a random website.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can call a procedure from a function in Oracle PL/SQL.

You can't call a procedure from a SELECT statement because it doesn't return a value.  A function can be called from a SELECT because it does:

```
select empno, calc_salary_function(empno) salary
from emp;
```

Calling a procedure from a SELECT makes no sense really:

```
select empno, fire_employee(empno) -- Will fail
from emp;
```

What would **you** expect to see in the second column of the results?

Answer (score 1):

Procedure is not used to return a value. Procedures performs group of operations to achieve a task, where as function is used to return a value.

Procedure is executed as an operation, function can be used in the select statement derive a value

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to validate that procedure can be called from inside function.

```
 create table country_name(id number, country varchar2(100));



insert all
into country_name values(1, 'INDIA')
into country_name values(2, 'UK')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
/



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COUNTRY_FOUND_NOTFOUND(V_NAME VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
V_COUNTRY VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNTRY INTO V_COUNTRY FROM country_name WHERE COUNTRY = V_NAME;
        RETURN 'FOUND';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            INSERT_COUNTRY(V_NAME);
            RETURN 'NOT FOUND';
    END;
    RETURN 'NOT FOUND';
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_COUNTRY(V_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
AS
V_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(ID) INTO V_ID FROM COUNTRY_NAME;
INSERT INTO COUNTRY_NAME VALUES(V_ID+1, V_NAME);
END;
/


SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
V_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
V_NAME := COUNTRY_FOUND_NOTFOUND('SPAIN');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_NAME);
END;
```

Comment: I believe your contention  "validate that procedure cant be" is a typo and should read  "validate that procedure **can** be". That is what it demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

you can call procedure from function.

```
 create table test(a varchar2(30));


 create or replace procedure pro_insert_values
 as
 begin
 insert into test values('anything');
 end;



 create or replace function fn_get_data
 return number 
 as

 begin
 pro_insert_values;
 return 1;  
 end;


 sql>variable x number
     exec :x:=fn_get_data
```